# WPF StackPanel content vertical alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, stackpanel

Is there a way in `XAML` to say that I want to center-align vertically all components inside a horizontal-oriented `StackPanel`?

I achieve the desired result with the below `XAML`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But I need to repeat the `VerticalAlignment="Center"` for each control separately.

Is there a way to declare on the `StackPanel` level something like below?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VERTICALCONTENTALIGNMENT="Center">
     <TextBlock/>
     <Button/>
     <TextBox/>
     <Button/>
     <TextBlock/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the `StackPanel` inside a `Grid` and set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` on the `StackPanel`

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        ...
    </StackPanel
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define style for `StackPanel` with `Trigger` which sets `VerticalAlignment` of all children:

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment"  Value="Center" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And apply this style:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanel}">
    <TextBlock />
    <Button />
    <TextBox />
    <Button />
    <TextBlock />
</StackPanel>
```

It works for me.
The whole code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HorizontalStackPanel" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment"  Value="Center" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanel}">
            <TextBlock Text="One"/>
            <Button Content="Two"/>
            <TextBox Text="Three"/>
            <Button Content="Four"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Five"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @Muds Where did you define HorizontalStackPanel Style?

Comment: in resources, and it seems exactly same problem with other answers

Comment: @Muds Resources of which element? I included the whole code.

Comment: of window, not to any individual element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75271/discussion-between-user2250152-and-muds).

Answer (score 1):

Define a style like this;

```
<Style x:Key="StackHorizontal" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"  Value="Center" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"  Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <TextBlock/>
     <Button/>
     <TextBox/>
     <Button/>
     <TextBlock/>
</StackPanel>
```